# EGit: how to update my branch with other merges

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am using EGit in Eclipse for version controls.

On Github, suppose that I fork a project by clicking the `Fork` button to create my own branch. And then, I import the project into Eclipse:

File --> Import --> Git --> Projects from Git --> Clone URI --> ...

I can then edit the project, commit, and push it as many times as needed.

After the work is done, I issue a `Pull Request` (PR) and the project owner may `merge` my branch to the original branch.

If there are also PR's and merges done by other members during my work, how do I get those updates into my project? Currently, what I do is delete my branch and Eclipse project after my PR, `Fork` the original branch to obtain the newest version, and then import the project into Eclipse, again.

Is there a standard/better way of doing this in Eclipse? I am thinking about the following procedure:

Fork branch --> Import --> Edit code --> Commit and Push --> Pull Request and merge --> *Get stuff from other merges* --> Edit code --> Commit and Push ...

In the above, how do I *Get stuff from other merges*? Thanks.

Please do not provide command line instructions. I need Eclipse procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that we need to add one more repository in the Git's `config` file, for example, the `main` repository:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/<myUsername>/blog
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "main"]
    url = https://github.com/<mainStreamUsername>/blog
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

in which, `origin` is my own repository and `main` is the main stream repository.

And then,

Right click project --> Team --> Pull ... (note: choose the one with three dots) --> Remote: choose `main` to pull from the main stream project.

Answer (score 0):

We can update our branch even by using eclipse IDE.
Follow the steps:

- 1. Right click on the project in which changes have been done.
- 2. Select "Team"
- 3. Select "Pull..."
- 4. Click on "New Remote"
- 5. Click on Finish.

It will pull the code and give you the updated code.

[Enter the details of the master branch or the branch from which you want to merge the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5nFj.png)